# Jquery select only what is in this DIV?

Tags: jquery, selector

HTML:

```
<div class="article">
<div class="article-content">
    <p><a href="javascript:;">Flygor</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et est sit amet eros inter dum auctor vel semper quam. Vivamus non purus amet.</p>
    <div class="wrap btn-actions">
        <div class="col"><a href="#" class="bt bt-medium" title="Retweet this" target="_blank">REPLY</a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="bt bt-large retweet">RETWEET</a><a href="javascript:;" class="bt bt-icon">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this Javascript:

```
    $('.retweet').click(function() {
    var retweetText =  $(this).('.article-content p').text();
});
```

So i want the p tag in the DIV.article-content, but just in this one.  I have about 10 article-contents on the page, and when the person clicks DIV.retweet i want to pull just the p tag in just that one DIV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Javascript is really close, actually. You need to use `.parents()` because `.article-content` is multiple parents above `.retweet`, then go down to the child, `p`.

EDIT:

As @ShaneBlake points out, `.closest()` is better suited for this situation. `.closest()` only grabs the first `.article-content` it traversed, while `.parents()` would grab them all. Therefore, the code is now.

```
$('.retweet').click(function() {
   $(this).closest('.article-content').children('p').text();
});
```

Comment: +1 for the only working example. (Also, [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/WHNvk/1/))

Comment: .closest() should be used instead of .parents().  The reason can be found in the API ( http://api.jquery.com/closest/ )

Comment: You're correct. Edited to use .closest(). Didn't know whether to replace entire answer, so I've left the original answer, but not the original code.

Comment: wow, super helful.  Thanks.  Quick additional question, if I want to target the anchor now?  How do I grab that?  I tried .children('p a') but that didn't work??

Comment: `.children('p').children('a')`

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
var retweetText =  $(this).closest('.article-content').children('p').text();
```

Comment: However the `<p>` isn't a parent of `.retweet`--It's a sibling of a parent. I could be wrong, but I believe you have to go up to do down.